# How to detect "delete" or "edit" events in popup menu created with Leaflet-draw-toolbar plugin?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, toolbar, leaflet-draw

In [this example](https://justinmanley.github.io/leaflet-draw-toolbar/examples/popup.html) you may create a polygon and then click it and popup menu shows. There is three buttons: edit, delete and pick a color. How can I detect event and determine which of it - delete or edit - was executed in popup menu? I want to perform some action when one of this events is executed e.g. when a polygon is edited or deleted. The standart way for it:

```
map.on('draw:created', function (evt) {
        layer = evt.layer;
        // do something when polygon is created
});

map.on('draw:edited', function (evt) {
        layer = evt.layer;
        // do something when polygon is edited
});

map.on('draw:deleted', function (evt) {
        layer = evt.layer;
        // do something when polygon is deleted
});
```

But for events in popup menu it doesn't work.

So I edited file `leaflet.draw-toolbar.js` and added my custom event `'draw-popup:edited'`

```
LeafletToolbar.EditAction.Popup.Edit = LeafletToolbar.ToolbarAction.extend({
...
    map.on('click', function () {
        shape.editing.disable();
        shape.fire('draw-popup:edited', shape);
    });
...
});
```

Now in my script file I'm able to detect `'draw-popup:edited'` event

```
layer.on('draw-popup:edited', function() {
        var geom = this.toGeoJSON();
        console.log(geom);

});
```

But now it's fired multiple times when I click on a map and returns all shapes that were edited.
What is the right way to detect event and return the shape that was edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this issue. This is fixed in the latest release of leaflet-draw-toolbar (0.2.1): https://www.npmjs.com/package/leaflet-draw-toolbar.

Comment: I think I am having the same problem with current version